# sql server management studio code completion

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've noticed that whenever I add tables / stored procs / functions / whatever to a sql server database, that it takes a while for the code completion to pick up that they are now part of the database.

This is really annoying since the code completion and syntax highlighting become totally broken in the workflow scenario where you create a table and then start writing queries or whatever that deal with this new object.

Does anyone know how to get the code completion / syntax highlighting engine to update it's view of what is in the database to get rid of all these spurious invalid object name errors?

Answer (score 6):

I understand that it's too late to answer the question but maybe it will help someone.

You can refresh the Intellisense cache with `Ctrl+Shift+R`, and wait for 5-10 seconds.

Comment: should be marked as answer. Short, correct, and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: Close and reopen SSMS? Lame and ineffective, and I hope there's a better way.